# Insert a newline between ){ in C code with `s` command

Tags: vim

I've a `C` file which has lines such as below

1.

```
  if(condition){
```

2.

```
int function(){
```

But I want the curly opening braces `{` in the next line. So that the code looks like this:

1.

```
if(condition)
{
```

2.

```
int function()
{
```

How do I achieve this with a single command in gVim?

Comment: Type "if (1 > u1Count)".  Hit <enter>. Type "{". Hit <enter> ...

Comment: I want to achieve that in a single search and replace command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:1,$s/){/)<CTRL>V<CTRL>M{/g
```

Should make it. `<CTRL>V` allows to insert a special character in the replace pattern. `<CTRL>M` (carriage return) is the special character. The rest is a classical vim substitute command.

Comment: You typed the <CTRL> literally. Replace them by a press of the CONTROL key of your keyboard: press the CONTROL key, do not release it, press the V key, release the V key, release the CONTROL key. Same with <CTRL>M. If it is too difficult, try the equivalent answer by luoluo.

Answer (score 2):

Try 
    `:%s/){/)\r{/g`

**Explanation:**

The `g` flag means global – each occurrence in the line is changed, rather than just the first.

`\r` is newline

[Search_and_replace in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)